# Как сделать несколько условий проверок на PHP?

Tags: php, if

Хочу сделать ряд проверок, пример для понимания:

1. Файл "index.php" в нем вызывается:

```html
<?php $master ="TEST"; and $a ="TEST-1"; or $b ="TEST-2"; or $c ="TEST-3"; ?>
<?php include('file/footer.html'); ?>
```

2. В файле "footer.html" имеется:

```html
<?php
if ($master == "Test" and $a == "TEST-1" or $b == "TEST-2" or $c == "TEST-3")

{ 
echo '
<p>Умом — Россию не понять,</p>
<p>Аршином общим не измерить:</p>
<p>У ней особенная стать —</p>
<p>В Россию можно только верить.</p>
<p>Автор, выберите правильный вариант: '.$a['Test-1'].' или '.$b['Test-2'].' или '.$c['Test-3'].'</p>
';
}

?>
```

3. И здесь возникает сложность, не знаю как правильно прописать, чтобы было следующее как результат:

```html
'.$a['Test-1'].' = Фёдор Иванович Толстой
'.$b['Test-2'].' = Фёдор Иванович Тютчев
'.$c['Test-3'].' = Фёдор Иванович Шаляпин
```

Спасибо! Заранее прошу извинить если не ясна точность описанного, ученик.

Comment: Вы напишите словами, что хотите сделать, потому что ваш код не имеет смысла, и по нему непонятно, чего вы хотите

Comment: ``<?php $a['Test-1'] = "Фёдор Иванович Толстой";?>`` Теперь когда мы будем выводить ``<?=$a['Test-1'];?>`` отобразится``Фёдор Иванович Толстой`` вы этого хотели?

Comment: Спасибо всем! Объясню простыми словами :)

Делаю главную проверку, пример: $master ="TEST" чтобы вывести контент - стихотворение.
Потом, дописываю к основной проверки "и" как продолжение, чтобы вывести ИО автора: Фёдор Иванович.
Ну и наконец, нужно вставить "или" чтобы уже вывести одну из фамилий (или несколько фамилий): Тютчев, Толстой, Шаляпин.

[Проверка и Вывод или Дополнение в выводу или Дополнение выводу]

Comment: @Nicolo понятнее не стало. То что Вы привели как пример главной проверки -- это присваивание, а не сравнение. Откуда внезапно берется ФИО автора, тоже не ясно, что за присваивание до `include` и почему между присваиванием `or` и `and`. Сама проверка работать верно не будет, так как часть с `AND` должна быть обернута в скобки. В проверке вы работаете с Вашими переменными, как с строками, а уже внутри, каким-то образом они становятся массивами.

Comment: @YaMus
 Можно и так, но если обратить внимание, то вызываемый участок находится в другом файле и там основная часть выводится после if ($master == "Test" ....

Comment: @Simon

- Вы усложняете понимание, все довольно просто. У меня вопрос вот в чем состоял. В отдельном файле есть пример такого: if ($master == "Test" and $a == "TEST-1" or $b == "TEST-2" or $c == "TEST-3")

- А, в файле INDEX.PHP имеется такая запись: <?php $master ="TEST"; and $a ="TEST-1"; or $b ="TEST-2"; or $c ="TEST-3"; ?>
<?php include('file/footer.html'); ?>

Вопрос. Где и как правильно заполнить значение: 

'.$a['Test-1'].' = Фёдор Иванович Толстой
'.$b['Test-2'].' = Фёдор Иванович Тютчев
'.$c['Test-3'].' = Фёдор Иванович Шаляпин

Comment: @Nicolo я Вам в принципе на ошибки в существующем коде указал. `<?php $master ="TEST"; and $a ="TEST-1"; or $b ="TEST-2"; or $c ="TEST-3"; ?>` -- этот код с синтаксическими ошибками, там или не должно быть `or` и `and` или объясните зачем это нужно, в противном случае будет `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "and"`. Так же и Ваша проверка не будет работать соответствующим образом. "Где и как правильно заполнить значение" -- да где угодно, на данный момент между этим и остальным кодом, нет особой связи.

Comment: @Nicolo по поводу Ваших же присваиваний где сначала `$a = "TEST-1" `, а потом внезапно это становится `$a['Test-1]`, будет ошибка `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string`, так как изначально это строка, с которой потом волшебным образом работают как с массивом.

Comment: @Simon

Такс...

- Мне нужно внутри "$master ="TEST"; " показывать ещё вот это "$a ="TEST-1";" и круто если ещё с выбором для "$a ="TEST-1";": "$b ="TEST-2";" или "$c ="TEST-3";".

Иными словами, главное это $master ="TEST" к ней добавляется ещё $a ="TEST-1" (а все остальное выбирается для последнего параметра: $b ="TEST-2"; или $c ="TEST-3";).

Вначале: стихотворение (обязательно), далее добавляется ИО автора (обязательно), и наконец выбирается Ф из вариантов для пункта ИО.

Comment: @Nicolo я не понимаю что такое `внутри "$master = "TEST"`, это просто операция присваивания значения переменной, где Вы задаете значение `TEST` переменной `$master`, что значит "внутри"? Все остальное точно так же не имеет смысла, Вы плохо понимаете что делает Ваш код, который Вы здесь описываете. В свою очередь `$a, $b, $c` это тоже переменные которым Вы присвоили значения `TEST-1, TEST-2, TEST-3` и все, о каком выборе речь вообще? Попробуйте описать лучше не сам код, а возможно привести какой-то use case.

Comment: Цель состоит в следующем:

1. На странице "index.php" вывести участок контента с файла "footer.html".
2. Выводимый контент на странице "index.php" должен состоять:

А) Из основной (обязательной части), например: Ура товарищи!
Б) Дополнительной части (как дополнение к основной), например: Кто это сказал?
В) И в конце я сам выбираю что выводить в продолжении дополнительной части контента, например: Ёжик / Попугай / Волк.


*Знак "/" в п.В в этом моём описании обозначает как раз "или" (выбор из вариантов).

Comment: На деле у Вас нет никакого выбора, для того чтобы был выбор, наверное необходимы какие-то интерактивные элементы, по типу радио-кнопки с вариантами выбора, чтобы Вы как пользователь, могли делать тот самый выбор. Присваивание значений в переменные Вам здесь никак не поможет.

Comment: @Simon

- Это я выбираю, а не пользователь. Контент я привел в пример, но логика применения как и описал. Когда выводится с другого файла основная часть контента, к ней дополнительная, а вот к дополнительной я сам как админ хотел бы выводить концовку.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$master ="TEST";
//$test_type ="TEST-1";
//$test_type ="TEST-2";
$test_type ="TEST-3";
$true_variants = [
    'TEST-1' =>['Фёдор Иванович Толстой'],
    'TEST-2' =>[
        'Фёдор Иванович Толстой',
        'Фёдор Иванович Тютчев',
    ],
    'TEST-3' =>[
        'Фёдор Иванович Толстой',
        'Фёдор Иванович Тютчев',
        'Фёдор Иванович Шаляпин'
    ],
  
];

if ($master == "TEST" and in_array($test_type,['TEST-1','TEST-2','TEST-3']) ){ 
    echo '
<p>Умом — Россию не понять,</p>
<p>Аршином общим не измерить:</p>
<p>У ней особенная стать —</p>
<p>В Россию можно только верить.</p>
<p>Автор, выберите правильный вариант: '.implode(' или ',$true_variants[$test_type]).'</p>
';
}
```

В зависимости от того какой `$test_type` раскомментируете - у вас будет 1 автор, 2 или 3 в результате. Другие `$test_type` нужно закомментировать для правильной работы

Comment: @Nicolo помогло?